# Prevent Double Click in JS for in browser game using Django 2.2

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-2.2

I have an issue where it requires the button to be clicked twice in order to initiate the functions. Except that the first click initiates `gameOver()` and a second click initiates a `gameOver()` again. But it takes two clicks to initiate `showGame()` and `hideStartBtn()` Therefore at the end of the timer ends it pops up two alerts since it loops twice.

Question is, How can I prevent double click and activate all the functions in a single click?

[Here is my repo](https://github.com/carlitos-206/js-browser-game-django)

JS - Snippet

```
function showGame() {
    var game = document.getElementById("the-game");
    if (game.style.display === "none") {
        game.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        game.style.display = "none";
    }
};
function hideStartBtn() {
    var StartBtn = document.getElementById("game-btn");
    if (StartBtn.style.display === "block") {
        StartBtn.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        StartBtn.style.display = "block";
    }
};
var killCount = 0;
function kill_1() {
    var killBtn = document.getElementById("kill-1")
    if (killBtn.style.display === "block") {
        killBtn.style.display = "none";
        killCount ++;
    } else {
        killBtn.style.display = "block";
    }
};

//This function repeats kill_1 - kill_7

function kill_7() {
    var killBtn = document.getElementById("kill-7")
    if (killBtn.style.display === "block") {
        killBtn.style.display = "none";
        killCount ++;
    } else {
        killBtn.style.display = "block";
    };
};
function gameOver() {
    var timeLeft = 10;
    var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 10000);
    var killGame = document.getElementById("the-game")
    function endGame(){
        if (killGame.style.display === "none"){
            killGame.style.display = "none";
            console.log("game ends here won")
        } else {
            console.log("game ends here lost")
            killGame.style.display = "none"
        }
    }
    function countdown() {
        console.log("time left:"+timeLeft)
        if (timeLeft == 0 || killCount !==7) {
            clearTimeout(timerId);
            timeLeft--;
            console.log("time left"+timeLeft)
            alert("YOU LOOSE!!!!");
            return endGame();
        } else { 
            clearTimeout(timerId);
            timeLeft--;
            console.log("time left"+timeLeft)
            alert("YOU WON!!!!");
            return endGame();
        }
    }
};
```

HTML - Snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {%load static%}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="{% static 'js/game.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}">
    <title>Browser Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gif-set-2">
        <img id="fish-gif"src="{% static 'img/animated-fish-mopping.gif' %}" alt="">
        <img id="floor-sign"src="{% static 'img/wavy-floor.gif' %}" alt="">
    </div>
    <button id="game-btn" onclick="hideStartBtn(), showGame(), gameOver()" >Tap to Clean</button>
    <div id="the-game" class="game">
        <button class="kill-btn" id="kill-1" onclick="kill_1()" ><img class="splatter" id="splat-1" src="{% static 'img/splat-1.png' %}" alt="splat"></button>
        <button class="kill-btn" id="kill-2" onclick="kill_2()" ><img class="splatter" id="splat-2" src="{% static 'img/splat-1.png' %}" alt="splat"></button>
        <button class="kill-btn" id="kill-3" onclick="kill_3()" ><img class="splatter" id="splat-3" src="{% static 'img/splat-1.png' %}" alt="splat"></button>
        <button class="kill-btn" id="kill-4" onclick="kill_4()" ><img class="splatter" id="splat-4" src="{% static 'img/splat-1.png' %}" alt="splat"></button>
        <button class="kill-btn" id="kill-5" onclick="kill_5()" ><img class="splatter" id="splat-5" src="{% static 'img/splat-1.png' %}" alt="splat"></button>
        <button class="kill-btn" id="kill-6" onclick="kill_6()" ><img class="splatter" id="splat-6" src="{% static 'img/splat-1.png' %}" alt="splat"></button>
        <button class="kill-btn" id="kill-7" onclick="kill_7()" ><img class="splatter" id="splat-7" src="{% static 'img/splat-1.png' %}" alt="splat"></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```